# PowerShell WPF add Click event for checkbox in combobox

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a combobox with custom DataTemplate that use Checkbox to show the items. The XAML code for combobox is:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbMyItems" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="21" Margin="6,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ischeck}" Content="{Binding name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In PowerShell code, I set ItemSource for it with following code:

```
$cbMyItems.ItemsSource = $itemlist
```

I have tried using handler with following code, but doesn't work.

```
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$handler = {
   Write-Host "Test"
}
$window.cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::CheckedEvent, $handler)
```

I also tried to add Click event to combobox, still does not work. Something like this:

```
$cbMyItems.Add_Click({})
```

How can I add Click event for the Checkbox in combobox datatemplate with PowerShell script?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @nimizen please see my edited post, I added what I have tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me assuming `$cbMyItems` is a valid reference to the `ComboBox`:

```
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$checkedHandler = {
    Write-Host "Check!"
}

[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$uncheckedHandler = {
    Write-Host "Uncheck!"
}

$cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::CheckedEvent, $checkedHandler)
$cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::UncheckedEvent, $uncheckedHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can add Click event based on your sample code now, but I cannot get clicked item object. Because I want to get clicked item then decide what operations I should do next. Could you please give more guidance to help me get the clicked item object?

Comment: I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110663/powershell-how-to-get-the-clicked-item-object-when-trigger-a-handler