# PowerShell how to get the clicked item object when trigger a handler

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a combobox with custom DataTemplate that use Checkbox to show the items. The XAML code for combobox is:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbMyItems" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="21" Margin="6,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ischeck}" Content="{Binding name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In Powershell, I use following code to set click event for the checkbox in combobox datatemplate.

```
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$uncheckedHandler = {
    
}

$cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::ClickEvent, $clickHandler)
```

The handler can be fired successfully. But I want to get the clicked item object then to decide what next operation.
I have tried use combobox's SelectedItem, but it returns "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:74" object, not the single item that I clicked in the dropdown.

I want to implement Select/UnSelect All function for my combobox. When I click "All" item, other items will be selected/Unselected. How can I get the clicked item object in the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the checked/unchecked `CheckBox` element like this:

```
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$uncheckedHandler = {
   $e = [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$args[1]
   $checkBox = [System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]$e.OriginalSource
   $dataObject = $checkBox.DataContext
   $itemName = $dataObject.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get the click item name now.

Answer (score 1):

To get the clicked item object in the handler when using a ComboBox with a custom DataTemplate, you can make use of the ComboBox's DropDownClosed event in combination with the SelectedItem property. Here's how you can modify your PowerShell code to achieve this:

```
# Define the Click event handler for the CheckBox
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$clickHandler = {
    $checkBox = $args[0]  # The CheckBox that was clicked
    $dataContext = $checkBox.DataContext  # The data context of the CheckBox

    # Now you can access properties of the clicked item using $dataContext
    $itemName = $dataContext.name
    $isChecked = $dataContext.ischeck

    # Perform your desired operations based on the clicked item
    if ($isChecked) {
        Write-Host "$itemName is checked."
        # Add your logic for a checked item here
    } else {
        Write-Host "$itemName is unchecked."
        # Add your logic for an unchecked item here
    }
}

# Add the Click event handler to the CheckBoxes
$cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::ClickEvent, $clickHandler)

# Define the DropDownClosed event handler for the ComboBox
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$dropDownClosedHandler = {
    $selectedItem = $cbMyItems.SelectedItem
    if ($selectedItem -ne $null) {
        # Perform your next operations using $selectedItem here
        # $selectedItem will contain the clicked item
        # You can access its properties as needed
    }
}

# Add the DropDownClosed event handler to the ComboBox
$cbMyItems.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox]::DropDownClosedEvent, $dropDownClosedHandler)
```

In this code, the '**Click**' event handler for the '**CheckBox**' gets the data context (which is the data item) of the clicked '**CheckBox**'. You can then access the properties of the clicked item ('**$itemName**' and '**$isChecked**') and perform your desired operations.

The '**DropDownClosed**' event handler for the '**ComboBox**' captures the selected item when the dropdown is closed, and you can access this item as **$selectedItem** to perform further operations based on the clicked item.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I want to implement select All function for the combobox. Once the "All" item selected/unselected, other items will be select/unselected. So I cannot wait the operations occurs when DropdownClosed, it's too late. In DropDownClosed event, I will check selected items, then fill the content to Combobox's Text value.